# What is the lifespan of a const char* in JNI?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working on a Android NDK-based code and I don't get how "long" is the lifespan of my string literals.
My program is a C++ game which interacts with the Android Java-side from time to time – like uploading data on servers, connecting to Facebook, etc.

In a downcall from Java to (native) C++, I use different ways to convert `jstring` to `const char*`, and I realized that some work but another doesn't. And I don't understand why.

E.g.: in a JNI downcall, where `toCall(const char*)` is a regular C++ function which is defined elsewhere.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_alpha_beta_Gamma_onDelta(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jstring jstr) {
   // #1
   const char* cVar = jnu::ToString(jstr).c_str();
   toCall(cVar);

   // #2
   std::string strVar = jnu::ToString(jstr); 
   toCall(strVar.c_str())

   // #3
   toCall(jnu::ToString(jstr).c_str());

   // #4
   std::string strVara;
   jnu::SetString(jstr, strVara);
   toCall(strVara.c_str());
}
```

And the `jnu` functions are:

```
std::string jnu::ToString(JNIEnv *env, jstring jstr) {
    if (jstr) {
        const char *cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, NULL);
        std::string str = cstr;
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, cstr);
        return str;
    }
    return std::string();
}

std::string& jnu::SetString(JNIEnv* env, jstring jstr, std::string& output) {
    if (jstr) {
        const char *cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, NULL);
        output = cstr;
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, cstr);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Cases `#2`, `#3` and `#4` work just fine, whereas `#1` just send plain garbage to the function to call.

Maybe it's C++ 101 but I don't get why my #1 case is buggy. Someone please give me any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char` array pointed to by the pointer returned by `std::string::c_str` is owned by the `std::string` instance.  That means that when the `string` that you called `c_str` on goes out of scope the data pointed to is deleted.

This is what happens in case #1.  The return value of `jnu::ToString` (or any other temporary) goes out of scope at the end of the expression, so as soon as you initialize `cVar` the data it points to gets deleted and you have a dangling pointer.  Any attempt to dereference a dangling pointer will result in undefined behavior.

In case #2 the `string` returned by `jnu::ToString` gets copied to `strVar` (or maybe moved, or maybe Return Value Optimization kicks in and no temporary ever actually gets created; it doesn't really matter).  The data pointed to by the pointer returned by `strVar.c_str()` will continue to exist until `strVar` goes out of scope or needs to reallocate its storage.

In case #3 the temporary `string` returned by `jnu::ToString` will continue to exist through the full expression, so it survives through the call to `toCall`.

Case #4 is similar to #2 except for how `jnu::SetString` fills `strVara`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Miles, for your comprehensive answer!